# Who is charged in a model of Mobile app using payment gateway

Tags: mobile, e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment

potentially it sounds a bit stupid my question, but honestly since i never worked with this kind of need, i would like to know exactly how the payment process works since i did not find any information that clearly answer this question to me.

So considering an e-commerce app using a payment gateway, who is charged for the transaction fees processed in context of user's order? Are the fees applied to the user, or are the fees applied to merchant?

If the fees are applied to the merchant, then is there any way to delegate these fees to be applied to the consumer?

So, i am trying to understand what is the correct way to have an mobile app processing orders and payments, without paying fees for it.

Thank you

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the merchant takes the brunt of the fees from the payment processor. You can pass the fees onto the customer, by incorporating it into your pricing model. Simply increase the price of the product to accommodate the fees. Stripe has a great article on this:

https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-i-charge-my-stripe-fees-to-my-customers

Note: Passing the fees to your customer is illegal in certain countries/jurisdictions, as mentioned in the above article

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the information. Nowadays, what is the most common way to other apps to deal with this? I presume that the app will not assume the costs of the operation, typically?!? I am talking about a scenario where the app allows to book and pay services, provided by third-party companies. So, the app is an intermediate between customer and service provider. @rickjerrity

Comment: I'm not sure there's any most common way, more what is best for your business. I'd imagine most companies charge a flat rate fee to help compensate for the payment processor fees, or maybe a variable fee based on payment method (again, depending on legality). If this answer helped you, please consider upvoting/marking as the answer. Cheers!